# GoDaddy/NameCheap servers or my own servers?

Tags: web-hosting, server, webserver

I am in Pakistan. Here we have the latest technology but we have frequent electricity loadshedding. If I want to start an online education system catering the students of Pakistan only, should I create my own servers or use GoDaddy/NameCheap servers?

Comment: It's not advisable to host servers in an environment where frequent power outages occur, to circumvent connectivity issues, data loss, etc... You would do better to use servers hosted in a more stable and reliable environment, preferably with data centers located geographically as close to your audience as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I always advise webmasters to use a hosting company that is in a reliable data center.  Hosting on your own webserver at home has many disadvantages:

- Less reliability due to power outages and ISP outages
- ISP restrictions on which ports are open
- Limited bandwidth (often throttled when running services)

The hosting company doesn't have to be GoDaddy.  In fact, GoDaddy doesn't have a stellar reputation as a hosting company.    See our related question: [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)